# How do I know if a third party library will work with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

[Expo](https://expo.io/) is great. One of it's goals is to use *only* javascript to write React Native apps.

How do you determine if a third party React Native library will work in the Expo development environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to look at the install instructions of the library.
If `react-native link` is mentioned then it **won't work** with Expo.

You can run any library by [Detaching to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/guides/detach.html) but you will lose some of the benefits of using Expo in the first place.

Comment: So based on your answer, i am unable to use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) as it requires `react-native link` and same goes for [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob). There is an expo version of [react-native-fs](https://github.com/expo/exponent-react-native-fs) but can't make it to work. can you please help me out in this?

Thanks

Comment: OK.. i made it to work with ExpoKit and Expo Detach. What are the benefits i am gonna lose other than running build inside Android studio? Thanks

Comment: I think that you won't lose anything else, but using exp is handy for builds, certs, etc.